# Ruby Rails collection select is displaying blank "prompt" value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, collections, prompt

I have a collection select like the following:

```
<%= f.collection_select :region_id, Region.find(:all), :id, :name, { :prompt => 'Select a State/Province' }, :style => "width: 200px;" %>
```

Sometimes the prompt from the :prompt option appears, but sometimes it does not.  Does anyone know where I could begin to troubleshoot this?  Maybe I have been looking at it too long...

Comment: Just to clarify: are you saying that the above exact code sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, or that you have two collection-selects with similarish code one one works and the other doesn't?

Answer (score 43):

`:include_blank` with the value of your blank option seems to do the trick. Try this:

```
 {:include_blank => "Please select"}
```

Comment: Just a gotcha to be aware of: this will not respect the string passed into `include_blank` if you are using `select_tag` method. Instead, use `prompt`.

Answer (score 13):

`:prompt` appears in the list when there isn't a selected value.

`:include_blank` appears in the list always, even if you've loaded the select with a selected value.

---

if you want your select to always have `"Select a State/Province"` as the first option:

```
<%= f.collection_select :region_id, Region.all, :id, :name, include_blank: 'Select a State/Province' %>
```

if you want your collection to have `"Select a State/Province"` as the first option only when a region is not already selected:

```
<%= f.collection_select :region_id, Region.all, :id, :name, prompt: 'Select a State/Province' %>
```

source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

Comment: `:prompt` also appears always, but is not selected on page load, if there is a selected value.

Comment: @AlexPopov I don't believe that is true. It seems that if your object has a value for, in this case, `region_id` when the form loads, the prompt value will not be there, whereas `include_blank` will be there.

Comment: @JoshPinter I am seeing the same problem: even after another value is selected, the prompt value is still a selectable option.

Comment: @EricChen Interesting. That's definitely not how it is supposed to work.

Comment: I'm facing this problem, anyone here could found a workaround? Thanks in advance. @EricChen

Answer (score 2):

I've been having the same problem. Using 'prompt' seems to create an attribute for the select tag, problem is there is no such attribute that I know of. Plus its clearly not what is described in the Rails docs http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select.

Using include_blank seems a good workaround for me.

Cheers, Robin.

Comment: If it is creating attributes, then you have to surround prompt with braces, like `{prompt: true}`. This separates the options hash for the Rails helper method from the attributes hash for the HTML element. Only the very last hash parameter of a method can go without braces.

Answer (score 0):

try this `<%= f.collection_select :region_id, Region.all, :id, :name, {prompt: 'Select a State/Province'},  {class: "form-control"} %>`

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. In future please add additional information when answering questions so that the OP and others in future can further understand your solution

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
:prompt => "Select a State/Province"
```

try

```
:allow_blank => "Select a State/Province"
```

EDIT: Yes after checking the API I can see that I had it confused, prompt is the correct way according to the documentation, could it be that it only sometimes it appears because your object has a value already and therefore the prompt is there but it is not the currently selected value in the drop down list???

Comment: thank you for verifying. however, the prompt does not even appear on the list when there is a selected value. it is non-existent.  for now, i have hacked it in JS, but i am a bit confused as to what is going on...

Comment: It's `:include_blank`. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html